# SQL Server 2019 Instalación "No se ha podido descargar un archivo necesario"

Tags: sql, sql-server, instalacion, sql-server-express, microsoft-sql

Quiero instalar `SQL-Server 2019`, pero al momento de descargar su instalador desde la misma pagina de Microsoft, al instalarlo me sale ese aviso, cuando le doy al link se descarga ese mismo instalador y cuando le doy a instalar me sale ese mismo aviso y así en un bucle, Necesito ayuda, Gracias!!

**Vaya... No se ha podido descargar un archivo necesario. Esto podría significar que la versión del instalador ya no se admite. Realice la descarga de nuevo sitio de descarga. https://www.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkID=866658**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se puede descargar directamente del link pero se encuentra en este[link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloadsue) el boton de descarga del Express

Answer (score 2):

El error es

> Vaya... No se ha podido descargar un archivo necesario. Esto podría
> significar que la versión del instalador ya no se admite. Realice la
> descarga de nuevo sitio de descarga.
> https://www.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkID=866658

o en idioma inglés:

> "A required file could not be downloaded. This could mean the version
> of the installer is no longer supported. Please download again from
> from the download site [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=866662"](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=866662%22)

El enlace que funciona es en realidad :

https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=866662

Una solución publicada en :

[**El instalador de SQL Server no puede descargar los archivos necesarios**](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/sql-server-installer-unable-to-download-the-required-files/m-p/2120065/highlight/true#M890)

es la siguiente, abrir `PowerShell` como administrador y ejecutar:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -Type Dword

Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -Type Dword
```

Comment: Funcionó perfectamente la solución, muchas gracias @Jorgesys

Comment: Excelente @antonioalopezfernandez , recuerda marcar como solución la respuesta que ayude a resolver el problema, revisar [tour] , saludos